# Why don't people use MAC Address instead of UDID on iOS5?

Tags: ios, ios5, udid

I've read Apple is deprecating the UDID which a lot of people are relying on to uniquely identify devices. However, there is an API to get the mac address which should also be unique. Why don't people use that?

Comment: Because although the MAC address is unique, it's actually quite a personal data item... eg, wireless networks that only allow specific devices online through their MAC address - they can be spoofed easily these days, but you would still need to know it somehow!

Comment: On many devices MAC address can be easily changed.

Comment: Does the iPhone have a single MAC address, or does each adapter have it's own MAC address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDID is not just used because of being unique. It is a tracking tool of iPhone for many purposes. As an example, many companies profile cellphone users for marketing purposes using UDID. In addition, the mac address of an iPhone can be easily retrieved by adjacent machines. But, the UDID should remain private always. [This link may](http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2010/12/19/unique-phone-id-numbers-explained/) be helpful.